# TypeError at / __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, init

I copied this code from maxg203 https://github.com/maxg203/Django-Tutorials
I had another errors but I managed to solve them but when it came to this one I stayed for a solid 4 hours trying to solve it and until now I didn't manage to
I am still a beginner in Django

My Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

my Views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from home.forms import HomeForm
from home.models import Post, Friend


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()

        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)
    return redirect('home:home')
```

My Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from home.models import Post


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Write a post...'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post',)
My urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from home.views import HomeView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url('connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(P<pk>\d+)/', views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
]
```

My Html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.post }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
            <p>Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Other People</h2>
        {% for user in users %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            {% if not user in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Friend</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <h2>Friends</h2>
        {% for friend in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=friend.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove Friend</button>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47,
 in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in
_get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[30/Sep/2020 16:45:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 60123
```

i am getting TypeError at /
**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Show your complete traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by putting _as.view in my project's  home URL